# Using Hauppauge HD PVR and Mac Mini to Stream Game Video

Tags: video, mac-mini

I recently acquired a [Hauppauge HD PVR](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_hdpvr.html) which my Xbox 360 is currently plugged into. I can record media from it using [HD PVR Capture](http://www.hdpvrcapture.com/cms/) or use it as a TV Recorder via [EyeTV](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/buy.en.html). Unfortunately, I want to take the raw video stream, and hook it into something like a Justin.TV or LiveStream ProCaster for live streaming purposes, but I can't figure out how.

The PVR is not listed as a "video device" like a camera, so I cannot choose it as a video source. Since this is a MacMini, there are no registered video devices listed in any app on the Mini (say for example, iMovie's "Import From Camera" section).

How can I take the video feed going into my Mac Mini via USB, and re-use it immediately for any video-like purpose?

Comment: And there went the bounty... ;_;

Answer (score 1):

Argh, I wish I had seen this in time for the bounty.

I do broadcasts using [Camtwist](http://allocinit.com/index.php?title=CamTwist). Camtwist will become a video source and it does things like just broadcast the desktop. So if you have EyeTV maximized and Camtwist broadcasting the desktop and your flash broadcasted using camtwist as a source, you should be set! If you want audio, [soundflower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/) is good for that, but not quite as straightforward as Camtwist. Might have to play with it. But there are lots of good tutorials on this online, give it a google.

Comment: I haven't bought EyeTV, and preferably don't want too. It's too expensive for such a niché use case. I won't use it often, and I don't have any TV service at home.

Comment: CamTwist also supports playing movies via a playlist. Maybe you can finagle it to play a movie while it is still recording? Sounds hokey, but another thought is that if you can somehow play a movie that is being recorded, then you could have camtwist output the desktop with that video playing and publish that as a video source??? I dunno.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, HD PVR Capture can show a preview in VLC Player while recording. Did you look into the 'streaming and transcoding options' in VLC Player?
Maybe you will find a solution in the [VLC forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=91577). CamTwist is probably easier.

You can [stream to Twitch with HDPVRCapture, OBS and SoundFlower](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rouoafm7Wfc)
or ffmpeg.